# how to run a query inside an option select php

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to run another query inside an option based on another query here is my code

```
<select name ="selectDiagnose" id = "Diagnose">
    <?php 
    $result2 = $user->con->query("SELECT * FROM `medical-history` WHERE patientID = '$row["ID"]' ");
     while ($row = $result2->fetch_array()){
         ?>
         <option value = '<?php $row2["ID"] ?>'> <?php echo "Name: ".$row2["name"]."  ,Date: ".$row2["date"]."  ,Type: ".$row2["DiagnosetypeID"] ?></option>
         <?php
     }
     ?>
</select>
```

the problem here that the type is in another table so i want to select the type of the diagnose base on the medical history diagnoseTypeID

```
<select name ="selectDiagnose" id = "Diagnose">
    <?php 
    $result2 = $user->con->query("SELECT * FROM `medical-history` WHERE patientID = '$row["ID"]' ");
    while ($row = $result2->fetch_array()){
        ?>
        <option value = '<?php $row2["ID"] ?>'> <?php echo "Name: ".$row2["name"]."  ,Date: ".$row2["date"]."  ,Type: ". **$user->con->query("SELECT type FROM `Diagnose type` WHERE ID = '$row["diagnosetypeID"]' ");** ?></option>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

how can i do that? and if there is another way ?

Comment: you can use join query

Comment: please, don't do this, do not run query in your view.. use mvc pattern please

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam yaah thank youu

Comment: @dariusz.g how can i use mvc here can you help explain more am new in all of this

Comment: you must learn how to use a MVC framework in the first place. having php, html, css, js in the same page it doesn't help you at all. the code is very messy and buggy, you'll end up easily with sql injection and other security issues. Use concatenation and sanitization of parameteres that you send to database. If you use PDO, use `->bindParam` or `->bindValue` to pass the query arguments. If you don't know what this is, stop right now what you're doing and learn

Comment: it's simple: m for model is your business logic (that is your query for example), v for view is your html or any other kind of view, c for controller is a kind of logic, which controls some interactions from view and responses with some data retrieved from model.

Comment: i know how to use mvc but i didnt know how to use it here in this select option how to separate php from html here and call php in each line

Comment: it's simple: put your query in another script and view in another, get all data you need from this query and simply include your view with populated data.

Comment: @dariusz.g the problem is in including my view with populated data i dont know how to do that every time in the while loop of the query

Comment: can you return a simple array as a query result (use joining tables) ? if you can then you can iterate on this array in your view using simple foreach loop.

Comment: no i dont know how to send variables from view to php file but i'll search for it, so i'll use php in my view just to iterate on this array right ?

Comment: simply use include 'view.php' at the end of query script

Comment: @dariusz.g okay thank youu

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note,

```
<?php $row2["ID"] ?>
```

doesn't do anything at all, you forgot to `echo` it. That being said, instead of running a query inside that depends on the value from your outer query, `JOIN` the queries instead and perform just one.

```
$result2 = $user->con->query("SELECT mh.*, dt.type  
                              FROM `medical-history` mh 
                              JOIN `Diagnose type` dt ON dt.ID=mh.diagnosetypeID
                              WHERE patientID = '".$row['ID']."'");
```

Also its worth noting that you should use parameterized queries with placeholders instead, using variables directly in the query may break it at best, or compromise your database at worst.

Answer (score 0):

better option use join query something like this

```
SELECT mh.*, dt.type  FROM `medical-history` mh LEFT JOIN `Diagnose type` dt ON dt.ID=mh.diagnosetypeID WHERE patientID = '".$row['ID']."'";
```

for more information about join

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

if you want to get type name without join query then check this

```
<select name="selectDiagnose" id="Diagnose">
    <?php
    $result2 = $user->con->query("SELECT * FROM `medical-history` WHERE patientID = '" . $row["ID"] . "'");
    while ($row = $result2->fetch_array()) {
        $result3 = $user->con->query("SELECT type FROM `Diagnose type` WHERE ID = '" . $row["diagnosetypeID"] . "'");
        $row_type = $result3->fetch_array();
        $type_name = $row_type['type'];
        ?>
        <option
            value='<?php $row2["ID"] ?>'> <?php echo "Name: " . $row2["name"] . "  ,Date: " . $row2["date"] . "  ,Type: " . $type_name ?></option>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```